# Spring 4 WebSocket + sockJS:. Getting "No matching method found" in trace and @MessageMapping handler not invoked

Tags: spring, websocket, stomp, sockjs, spring-4

Controller code:

```
@Controller
public class SockController {

    @MessageMapping(value="/chat")
    public void chatReveived(Message message, Principal principal) {
        ...
        LOGGER.debug("chatReveived message [{}]", message);
        ...  
    }
}
```

WebSocketConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@EnableScheduling
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/queue/", "/topic/");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/portfolio").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

Javascript:

```
        var socket = new SockJS('/portfolio');
        var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
            ...
        });
        stompClient.send("/app/chat", {}, JSON.stringify(message))
```

With these code, the frontend is able to connect with server over WebSocket and send message. But @MessageMapping handler method chatReveived() doesn't get called.

frontend output:

```
Opening Web Socket...
Web Socket Opened...
>>> CONNECT
accept-version:1.1,1.0
heart-beat:10000,10000

<<< CONNECTED
user-name:1
heart-beat:0,0
version:1.1

>>> SEND
destination:/app/chat
content-length:35

{"from":{"userId":1},"text":"ssss"}
```

server output:

```
[21:19:26.551] TRACE org.springframework.web.socket.handler.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator: TextMessage payload= SEND
desti.., byteCount=82, last=true], SockJsSession[id=mdibjok1, state=OPEN, sinceCreated=8504, sinceLastActive=8504]
 - 
[21:19:26.551] DEBUG org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompDecoder: Decoded [Payload byte[35]][Headers={stompCommand=SEND, nativeHeaders={content-length=[35], destination=[/app/chat]}, simpMessageType=MESSAGE, simpDestination=/app/chat, id=b7f01f0b-db3e-911d-60dc-c7275f8ef306, timestamp=1407201566551}]
 - 
[21:19:26.551] TRACE org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.StompSubProtocolHandler: Received message from client session=mdibjok1
 - 
[21:19:26.551] TRACE org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel: [clientInboundChannel] sending message id=0f482da7-fee0-d8f1-4b47-bd993eaee80d
 - 
[21:19:26.551] TRACE org.springframework.messaging.support.ChannelInterceptorChain: postSend (sent=true) message id 0f482da7-fee0-d8f1-4b47-bd993eaee80d
 - 
[21:19:26.552] DEBUG org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler: Handling message, lookupDestination=/chat
 - 
[21:19:26.553] DEBUG org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler: No matching method found
 - 
[21:19:26.553] TRACE org.springframework.messaging.simp.broker.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler: Ignoring message to destination=/app/chat
 - 
[21:19:26.554] TRACE org.springframework.messaging.simp.user.DefaultUserDestinationResolver: Ignoring message to /app/chat, not a "user" destination
```

Seems like it is not able to find the handler method. Any idea where I was wrong?

My environment is: Tomcat 8.0.9, Spring 4.0.6 RELEASE, Spring security 3.2.4.RELEASE, JDK 7

Comment: i have a very similar problem, did you ever find the root cause of this please? It seems my json is not being matched to the method's parameter which is a POJO of the json string I am sending. If you ever found the problem please let me know :)

Answer (score 4):

WebSocketConfig configuration class should be loaded as part of Servlet configuration, not Root configuration.

Make sure `WebSocketConfig.class` returned from your implementation of `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.getRootConfigClasses()`

If you put it in root context, everything will work fine, you can use SimpMessagingTemplate, broker relay, but not @MessageMapping in controllers.

You can set breakpoint in `WebSocketAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.initControllerAdviceCache()` and check what beanss are loaded in context. If no `@Controller` marked bean in that method, `@MessageMapping` will not work.

Comment: Indeed, make sure you have ```@Controller``` annotation, not ```@Service```

Comment: Bro, 6 years later you still save people from pulling out hair from frustration. That did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try @ComponentScan in WebSocketConfig so that Spring can find the Controller.